# React - Google Map component not change map after re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with Google Map in React.
Everything works great but, when I try to re-render other place in this map it doesnt work :( 
I mean when I change city (e.g. select) new props (latitude, longitude) are used , but city one the map not change

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps";

const SimpleMapExampleGoogleMap = withGoogleMap( props => {
    console.log("here new props are used", props)
    return <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={15}
      defaultCenter={new google.maps.LatLng(props.lat, props.lng)}
    />
 }
);

class GMap extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lat: this.props.lat,
            lng: this.props.lng
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log("New props ", this.props)

        return <SimpleMapExampleGoogleMap
                lat={this.props.lat}
                lng={this.props.lng}
                containerElement={
                  <div style={{ height: `500px` }} />
                }
                mapElement={
                  <div style={{ height: `500px` }} />
                }
            />
    }
}
export { GMap }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have set state for `lng` and `lat` but you didn't apply them on the map

=> change `this.props.lat` to `this.state.lat`, and same for the `lng`:

```
    return <SimpleMapExampleGoogleMap
            lat={this.state.lat}
            lng={this.state.lng}
            containerElement={
              <div style={{ height: `500px` }} />
            }
            mapElement={
              <div style={{ height: `500px` }} />
            }
        />
```

If the above code doesn't update your map yet, then feel free to add the following method (same level as constructors):

```
  constructors(props){/*...*/}

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({
      lat: nextProps.lat,
      lng: nextProps.lng,
    });
  }

  render(){/*...*/}
```

Please also post here if you have errors, thanks

Comment: Thank You very, very much  * 100 :) it works, 
Omg I didn't think about componentWillReceiveProps
You made my day :) 
P.S no errors :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad you made it work ^^ ! For further issues related to ReactJS or Google/Leaflet maps, feel free to ping me!